# How to use <front> tag in views?

Tags: views

I have a site on Drupal 7, where I'm using Views with Multilingual settings.
I have 2 languages, Russian and English.

On the front page, I have created a "Latest News" block with Views.
Each news item has a link to the full article like the following ones:

- example.com/en/news/1
- example.com/ru/news/1

This block is also shown on some other pages, such "Services - > Service 1"  shown at example.com/en/services/service-1.

The problem is that on my block I use global text to format the output of the latest news; the link is built using the following:

```
<h2><a href="./news/[nid]">[title]</a></h2>
```

It works fine on the front page, but when I'm on the Services page, the news link is similar to example.com/en/services/news/1,which is incorrect; Drupal gives me an error about a not existing page.

Is there a way to reference the front page with any tag I can use in the "Global Text" settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php filter, or install [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module and then enable tokens in filter which you use (admin/config/content/formats). Token for front page is [site:url] so you should write your link like follow:

```
<h2><a href="[site:url]news/[nid]">[title]</a></h2>
```